# Mixed effects model with zero inflated data - Error message using zeroinfl() from 'pscl' package

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, poisson, pscl

I am having issues with the function `zeroinfl()` from the 'pscl' package. Here is an overview of my situations:

I am trying to find out if the non-native stem density in a plot is influenced by the focal species at that plot. I am using a mixed effects model with the random effect being the site (I collected data at 6 different sites). This is what the mixed model looks like using the `glmer()` function from the 'lme4' package:

```
nonstem.model <- glmer(nonstem ~ focalspecies + (1|site), family = "poisson", data = data, na.action=na.omit)
```

The problem is that my data is zero inflated, meaning that there were a lot of plots with no non-native species present. So I tried using the `zeroinfl()` function from the 'pscl' package.

```
nonstem.ZIP = zeroinfl(nonstem ~ focalspecies + (1|site), dist="poisson", link = "logit", data = data)
```

But I received an error message:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels In
>   addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(1, site) : ‘|’ not meaningful
>   for factors

So I gathered that I cannot have a random effect here, and so I changed it to a fixed effect.

```
nonstem.ZIP = zeroinfl(nonstem ~ focalspecies + site, dist="poisson", link = "logit", data = data)
```

However, now I am getting this error message:

> Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) :    system is
>   computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.70937e-36

If I change the distribution from "poisson" to "negbin" then a similar error message comes up:

> Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) :    system is
>   computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.92265e-19

Does anyone know what this error message means? Or if there is a different package/function that I can use? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [`glmmTMB`](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB) allows fitting ZI Poisson mixed effect models.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you, this works! This is what it looks like:
`nonstem.ZIP = glmmTMB(nonstem ~ focalspecies + (1|site), family = "poisson", data = data, na.action=na.omit, ziformula=~1)`
But now I am unable to run a type II Anova. Normally I would use the `Anova()` function from the "car" package. But when I try to do so I get this error message: `Error in I.p[c(subs.relatives, subs.term), , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds`
If I try to run `plot()` then I get this message: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your comment, you can use base R's `stats::anova` to compare two models.

Here is a reproducible example using the `Salamanders` sample data from `glmmTMB`

```
library(glmmTMB);
fit1 = glmmTMB(
    count ~ spp * mined + (1|site),
    zi = ~ spp * mined,
    data = Salamanders,
    family = poisson);
fit2 = glmmTMB(
    count ~ spp + mined + (1|site),
    zi = ~ spp + mined,
    data = Salamanders,
    family = poisson);

anova(fit1, fit2)
#Data: Salamanders
#Models:
#fit2: count ~ spp + mined + (1 | site), zi=~spp + mined, disp=~1
#fit1: count ~ spp * mined + (1 | site), zi=~spp * mined, disp=~1
#     Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
#fit2 17 1785.5 1861.4 -875.75   1751.5
#fit1 29 1778.1 1907.7 -860.04   1720.1 31.405     12   0.001708 **
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Credit where credit is due: The example was adjusted from [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/257).

Comment: can you explain why you've included spp and mined under the zi term?

Comment: @tnt `zi` (short for `ziformula`)  defines the terms used for the zero-inflation. For example, `zi = ~ 0` means no zero inflation; in the example above we consider only the fixed terms `spp + mined` and `spp * mined`, respectively, in the zero-inflation model.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits Evers. I was curious because I've only observed the zi = ~1 for zero inflation, not actual terms specified.  Is this because you expect those terms (as well as the response) to be zero-inflated?  Or something else?

Comment: @tnt The zero-inflation model (ZIM) is a (linear) model that describes the occurrence of structural zeros that are not described by the conditional (GLM or nested-effect) model. As such, the ZIM can have any number of predictors. Coefficients of the ZIM then characterise the dependence of these extra zeros on your predictors. If you set `zi ~ 1` then the ZIM is assumed to be independent of any predictors. In the example above, we assume the ZIM to depend on the fixed effect terms. [...]

Comment: [continued] Mind you, I've only copied the example above from a post on GH. Which terms to include in the ZIM would depend on your specific situation.

Comment: [continued 2] Perhaps another way to look at the terms in `ziformula` is in the context of a data generating process: `ziformula` should include those terms that are believed to be involved in generating these "additional" zeros.